# How to make a contingency table for a one multiple choice question?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I need to make a cross table for only one question with multiple choice.

I have a survey results. The idea is to see share of people who know Brand1 and also know other brands.

Lets say we have an input table with answers:

```
Id  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
1   1       1       0       1
2   0       0       1       1
3   1       1       0       0
4   1       0       0       1
5   0       0       1       1
6   0       0       1       0
7   1       1       0       1
```

We making a cross table with sum of answers for each brand:

```
        Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
Brand1  4       3       0       3
Brand2  3       3       0       2
Brand3  0       0       3       2
Brand4  3       2       2       5
```

And then calculate the column percent from all who knows each brand:

```
        Brand1  Brand2  Brand3  Brand4
Brand1  100%    100%    0%      60%
Brand2  75%     100%    0%      40%
Brand3  0%      0%      100%    40%
Brand4  75%     67%     67%     100%
```

I tried to adapt dax pattern for surveys (https://www.daxpatterns.com/survey/) by Marco Russo and Alberto Ferrari. It works with different questions of the survey but not with the same one - shows empty cells at the intersection

Answer (score 0):

There are likely better ways of doing this but here's one way.

I would suggest you re-work the data table using power query so you end up with a table looking like this:

[image]

This is done by starting with your example data table, unpivote the Brand columns, and then crossjoining the table with its self using the id column as link. (I renamed the [value] column from after the unpivoting to [Known_TF] and the new [value] column from after the crossjoin to [AlsoKnown_TF], same for Brands and AlsoKnownBrands)

Then create two new dimensions table, both of them holding only unique values of brands. Yes, two identical tables. Name one "Known" and the other "Also_known".

In the relations view in Power Bi create a 1:* relationship between 'Known'[Brand] and 'Data'[KnownBrand], and a 1:* between 'Also_Known'[Brand] and 'Data'[AlsoKnownBrand], like ths:

[image]

Now write two measures:

```
Value = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[AlsoKnown_TF]);
    'Data'[Known_TF] = 1
)
```

and:

```
Value_pct = 
DIVIDE(
    [Value];
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Data'[AlsoKnown_TF]);
        ALL('Data'[Known_TF])
    );
    0
)
```

On a dashboard, use the matrix visual. Put 'Known'[Brand] as column, 'Also_Known'[Brand] as row, and the measures as values. You end up with something like this:

[image]

N.B. It is not technically necessary to create the two dimensions tables, you can skip that part and thus also the relationship part of the solution. In the matrix, use the 'Data'[KnownBrand] as column and 'Data'[AlsoKnownBrands] as rows and you'll end up with the same result. Though, I believe from a computational performance point of view it's better using the two dimensions tables, but please correct me if I'm wrong.